# Dynamically Loading CSS based on PHP Sessions, A Better Way?

Tags: php, html, css

I want to generate a CSS file depending on the user's logged in state. I have no issue with the PHP sessions, I'm just having a hard time dynamically generating CSS and I don't like my solution, even though it works.

(I want to present a completely different CSS file to users depending on their logged in state.)

Instead of just pointing to the correct CSS file where you have the various CSS files in a folder and just change the pointer, such as:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php echo $correctStylePath; ?>'>
```

I thought it would be pretty neat to actually allow access to the files depending on their logged in state. (I want to prevent access to CSS files that they are not meant to be able to see.)

This meant not allowing the incorrect CSS to be in public view at all.

I couldn't figure out a way to present different files depending on the session, so I made this hack which seems to be rather crude.

Instead of making available a different CSS file or the same CSS with different contents, I just load all of the CSS into the head of the HTML document.

Is there a better way to do this that allows me to keep the CSS in its own file?

**index.php**

```
<?php
    // Now we can check for user
    if(isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && isset($_SESSION['Username'])){
        $includeMode = "LoggedIn";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home (Logged In)</title>
<?php
    require_once 'styles.css.php';
?>
</head>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
<?php
    }else{
        $includeMode = "LoggedOut";
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home (Logged Out)</title>
<?php
    require_once 'styles.css.php';
?>
</head>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

**styles.css.php**

```
<?php

$fileLocation = '';

if($includeMode == 'LoggedIn'){

    $fileLocation = '../css/styles-logged-in.css';

}else if($includeMode == 'LoggedOut'){

    $fileLocation = '../css/styles-logged-out.css';

}else{

    die();
}

$stylesFile = fopen($fileLocation, 'r') or die("Unable to open file!");

print "<style>";
print fread($stylesFile, filesize($fileLocation));
print "</style>";

fclose($stylesFile);

?>
```

Comment: Why would you do that? better approach is doing something like this in javascript.

Comment: Why would you generate CSS ? Just use a body class like user-logged-in and user-not-logged. (this way, user will only have to load one stylesheet)

Comment: I don't get the restriction either. Would probably just assign a specific class to the html or body tag and have one CSS files where it shows different styles based on that class. Makes caching much easier

Comment: You're both right, although it's more about seeing if I can make it prevent access to certain CSS for logged out users. I guess it's actually more along the lines of, can I do this? Rather than something super practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a PHP page called `style.php`, set the headers to CSS and then output depending on the `$_SESSION` variable, followed by altering your `.htaccess` file.

For example, in the `<head>` of your *homepage*:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>
```

---

In *`style.php`*:

```
session_start();
header("Content-type: text/css");

if(isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && isset($_SESSION['Username'])){ ?>

    /* Put your CSS for logged-in users here */

<?php } else { ?>

    /* Other CSS here */

<?php } ?>
```

---

Then, in *`.htaccess`* in your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^style\.css$ style.php [L]
```

This means that if you visit `/style.css` you will see the output of `/style.php`, which will be the relevant stylesheet.

One caveat of this is that browser caching would be an issue as it would cache one stylesheet *or the other*, so styles would not be consistent unless browser caching is off (but that will slow down your site).

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a dynamic language so use it as one. you dont have to creat to html tags for each if else statement. make php fill the gap depending on your conditional statement.
CSS files are not called by required function but included using HTML `**<link>**` tag and call the CSS file required by php in that tag.

```
 <?php
    // Now we can check for user
    if(isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && isset($_SESSION['Username'])){
        $includeMode = "LoggedIn";
        $cssFileName = 'LoggedIn.css';
    }else{
        $includeMode = "LoggedOut";
        $cssFileName = 'LoggedOut.css';
    }


<html>
<head>
    <title>Home (<?php echo $includeMode; ?>)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/main.css">
    // below link tag will overrule the above one if same element style has been defined in both files
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/<?php echo $cssFileName; ?>">
</head>
<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah something like this is better. 
One thing I would say though is have a main.css file - for most styles, some base stuff that you would have. Then if the use is logged in include another css that would overrule that css

Comment: yes just add that after the main css. I am going to update the answer give me 2 min